# How to compare the current row to the next row of a mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I want to compare the current row to the next to check if the third column of the current row is the same as to the next. If not, the current row index will adjust as the new current row and check again the next row. I want to do this in `php`. Can somebody help me.

UPDATED:

```
ID    |   Date    | Time
------+-----------+-------
00091 | 2015-1-20 | 08:05
00091 | 2015-1-20 | 17:10
00099 | 2015-1-20 | 07:45
00099 | 2015-1-20 | 17:42
```

my expected outputs are:

```
ID    |   Date    |    Time
------+-----------+-------------
00091 | 2015-1-20 | 08:05 17:10
00099 | 2015-1-20 | 07:45 17:42
```

Comment: kindly update ur question with sample data and expected output.

Comment: what row(s) and what column name(s) are we dealing with?

Comment: they are ID, Date and Time

Comment: I'm still not getting how you are deriving the expected output.What i understood is If ID's are same you want all the time corresponding to that ID in same row? am i correct?

Comment: Yes, they are defined by each date also meaning in one date the user must have at least 1 time and a maximum of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a *terrible* database design, so I would **highly** recommend changing it! Having duplicate IDs hurts me deeply.

But, here's a MySQL query that could get the result you are after:

```
SELECT `ID`, `Date`, CONCAT(MIN(`Time`), ' ', MAX(`Time`)) AS `Time`
FROM `test`
GROUP BY `ID`, `Date`;
```

Comment: BTW, you can also concatenate/join those fields using PHP, but it would be much easier and faster to do that in a SQL query.

Comment: what is the meaning of 1?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the `WHERE 1` - it doesn't affect the output.

Comment: BTW, not sure about the data types of those fields either, so your query results could vary based on that.

Comment: How to do this via php?

Comment: Can't you just modify the SQL query being used in your PHP? It's much messier via PHP and you would need to show a bit more of your code.

Comment: I will try that also but I want to see also in php for future reference.. Thanks